# Can't reindex with LiteMage disabled

Tags: reindex, indexer, litespeed, litemage

I disabled the extension Litespeed_Litemage because I don't need it on my dev environment, but now I get...

**Category Products index Abort: LiteMage is not enabled**

...when trying to reindex.

Comment: try this https://docs.litespeedtech.com/lscache/litemage/troubleshoot/